# Is tree shaking an actual thing?

Tags: webpack, angular, tree-shaking

I have been reading about how to make tree shaking work and about how to workaround the issues that is has with webpack and typescript and uglify and I can't seem to make it work.

What are the simplest steps to make tree shaking work in a completely new Angular4 project? (project generated with `ng create foobar-project`).

Comment: Why are you trying to do that on your own ? `ng build --prod --aot` do that for you, the tree shaking being much more efficient in Ahead Of Time compilation mode

Comment: @bviale is there a way I can enable tree shaking in "ng serve" so I can check the final size while working on my code?

Comment: well `ng serve` is used to work locally on your code. Why would you optimize your build size while working on it ? Better keep sourcemap while coding and occasionnaly check your future production build size right ? Otherwise you can still work on your production build by using an external hosting system such as `http-serve` instead of `ng serve`

Comment: You can do that with ng serve too, but it doesn't seem like a good idea as it'll take more time before reloading on every change. You can try : `ng serve --prod --aot` but as @bviale said, you should rather do that when building, not while you're working on something

Comment: I don't think `--prod` is available on `ng serve` since it is not mentioned in the wiki : https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/serve
The output js won't be minified I guess